# Safari extension send message to a specific tab

Tags: javascript, safari, add-on, safari-extension, browser-extension

Is there a way to send a message from the global page to a *specific tab*? 
What I'm currently doing is, on tab creation the injected script creates a unique id and sends a message with this number to the global page and the global page saves this number.  
If the global page needs to send some data to a tab (i.e: tab `#3`) then the global page will "broadcast" a message to all tabs with the number `#3` as part of the data passed to the tabs (iterate over all tabs and send a message to each tab). 
Is there something like Chrome: (i.e: `chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabID, {action: 'respond', params:[channel,msg,async]});`)?

Right now what I'm doing is that on the injected script side, each script has a listener that will catch this message. If a content script unique number is equal to the number sent by the global page then this message is for it, else `doNothing`.

Is there an easier more elegant way to do this in Safari?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the global page's message event handler, `event.target` refers to the tab from which a message was received. For example:

```
function handleMessage(e) {
    if (e.name === 'whatIsMyUrl?') {
        e.target.page.dispatchMessage('yourUrlIs', e.target.url);
    }
}
safari.application.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
```

The Safari extension API doesn't have tab IDs, but you could just keep each tab in an associative array and use its index to address it later. For example:

```
function handleMessage(e) {
    if (e.name === 'hereIsMyId') {
        myTabs[e.message] = e.target;
    }
}
safari.application.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);

// later...
myTabs[someId].page.dispatchMessage('haveSomeCake');
```

Answer (score 1):

Safari Answer

In your global page save directly to the tab.. so for instance on message from injected script

```
// global page
safari.application.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    switch(event.name){
        case "saveData":
            event.target.page.tabData = { data: myData }
        break;
        case "getData":
            event.target.page.dispatchMessage("tabData", myData);
        break;
    }
}, false);
```

-

```
// injected page

// first save data
safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("saveData", {firstname:"mike", age: 25} );

// setup listner to recevie data
safari.self.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    switch(event.name){
        case "tabData":
            // get data for page
            console.debug(event.message);
            // { firstname: "mike", age: 25 }
        break;
    }
}, false);

// send message to trigger response
safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("getData", {} );
```

Comment: and you'd have to do additional stuff to handle new safari with many pages fetched ahead of time i think